# How to use BASE64Encoder().encode(bytes) in parallel threads

Tags: java, multithreading, encoding

I am using the `sun.misc.CharacterEncoder.encode(bytes)` method to encode strings in 10 parallel threads.

I observed that this encode method is trying to access the `System.getProperty()` which in turn is accessing the `Hashtable.get()` method that is synchronized. Due to this, the other 9 threads are going into a blocked state and only one thread is in an active state which is affecting the performance.

Can we do anything here to not to block the other threads? Or any suggestions to use other methods for encoding?

Comment: I cannot find in javadoc a method or class named exactly BASE64Encoder. Can you write the full path of the class or the exact method. Also java version and an example of your code will be useful.

Comment: If you want to improve performance, don’t store all of your data in a single byte array;  base-64 encode bytes directly from an InputStream.

Comment: It's my bad. I am using sun.misc.CharacterEncoder.encode(byte[]) method not the BASE64Encoder

Comment: What Java version are you using? If Java 8 or higher, then you should use `java.util.Base64`. Don't use classes from the `sun.misc.*` namespace.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarkRotteveel. Its working as expected.